# Is the GRE general test score necessary for the 2024-2025 year?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, exams, gre

I am an international student from Georgia. I’m aiming to enroll in a Ph.D. program in mathematics in the 2024-2025 year. I’ve already passed the TOEFL Exams and the GRE subject test. Is it necessary to also take GRE general test? Do I stand a chance without the GRE general score?

Comment: Some schools will require it, some make it optional, and others ignore it. There is no general answer for the US. It is a difficult test, but my experience was that I did far better than I thought I'd done when I exited the exam. Very broad set of questions. More than most have studied. But the grading accounts for that.

Comment: Agree with Buffy. The same applies to GRE Subject.

Comment: I think the most general answer we can have, is that given to this related question: [Status of the GRE exams for PhD programs in mathematics in 2023](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/201703/17254)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the schools you are applying to. To be on the safe side, I'd take the general test anyway since you have already taken the subject GRE and TOEFL tests. With all 3 tests taken, you can apply to almost any school in the US/Canada (for a Ph.D. in Math/Applied Math), and, additionally, with the general test you might even explore interdisciplinary PhDs in some of the engineering schools if you are interested. Good luck!